# Algebra of exponential

Tags: linear-algebra, exponential-function

Solve for $x$ in exact value:

$\\3^{2x}-3^{x+2}+8=0$

I have tried substituting $3^x$ $=a$ but I didn't get anywhere.

$\\a^2-a^{1+\frac{2}{x}}+8=0$

Comment: why didn't you get anywhere? try again.

Comment: You'll get $a^2-9a+8=0$, which is just a quadratic equation.

Comment: You didn’t get $a^2-9a+8=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$3^{2x}−3^2*3^x+8=0$$
Substituting $3^x =a$:
$$a^2-3^2*a+8=0$$
$$a^2-9a+8=0$$
$$(a-1)(a-8)=0$$
$$a_1=1, a_2=8$$
Final answer:
$$x_1=0, x_2=log_38$$

Comment: I see now my mistake sorry for bothering you. I will accept your answer when I could

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\log_x(y)=z\Longleftrightarrow x^z=y$

$$8+3^{2x}-3^{x+2}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Substitute $y=3^x$:

---

$$y^2-9y+8=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(y-9)(y-1)=0$$

So we got:

- $$y-9=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
  $$y=9\Longleftrightarrow$$
  $$3^x=9\Longleftrightarrow$$
  $$x=\frac{\ln(8)}{\ln(3)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
  $$x=\log_3(8)$$
- $$y-1=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
  $$y=1\Longleftrightarrow$$
  $$3^x=1\Longleftrightarrow$$
  $$x=0$$

Comment: $y=9$ is a typo.